# Resource to start with JavaScript quickly?

Tags: programming-languages, learning, javascript

Previously, I wanted to learn Python quickly: 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49755/resource-to-start-with-python-quickly
and I was quite successful (enough to write a simplified LISP interpreter).

Now I need to learn JavaScript for some web programming using Prototype and Scriptaculous with Ruby on Rails.

Are there any resources to learn JavaScript quickly in reasonable depth? I am not a beginner programmer, but I have no experience with JavaScript.

Are there any good quick tutorials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Learn JavaScript with MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript)

A set of tutorials from the Mozilla developer network. These are a bit too generally aimed. If I were to pick one article I would pick [Re introduction to javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript)

If you want to pick up the particularities of JavaScript look at [The JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/)

The [official introduction](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn) to prototype on their page is a good start for learning prototype. You can read the documentation for any other specifics.

Comment: I would appreciate something even shorter, if you know of something. The official Prototype documentation is really good, thanks:)

Comment: @GabrielScerbak the garden is really short for JavaScript :) and added the re introduction link which is solid enough to start with

Comment: @GabrielScerbak another learning resource is asking lots of simple questions on stackoverflow and talking in [JavaScript chat @ SO](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript)